# Prove that the series $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_n$ converges if and only if $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n$ converges.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis, limits

Is the easiest way showing the Partial Sums converge and then  $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n$ is a sub-series of  $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_n$ hence is converges ? If that's the case, then how would I do that ?

Comment: Yes, $\{s_n\}$ converges if and only if $\{t_n\}$ converges, with $t_n = s_n-a_0$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One may observe that
$$
\sum_{n=0}^N a_n=a_0+\sum_{n=1}^N a_n
$$if the left hand side converges, as $N \to \infty$, so does the right hand side and *vice versa*.

Comment: Your displayed equation doesn't make sense. For example, let $a_n = (-1)^n, n = 0, 1,2,\dots $ What sense does $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^n = 1 + \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^n$ make?

Comment: @zhw. Thanks for the feedback. I've taken your remark into account.

Comment: As a general rule of good thinking, you need to understand that the behavior of a serie is **not** dependant  on any number of its first terms. In maths language :

$$\lim_{k=1}^\infty \sum u_n      \Leftrightarrow  \lim_{k=N}^\infty \sum u_n, \forall N$$
(Note that this notation should only be used when $\lim \sum$ is defined)